# Is there any way to force my initial villagers houses to become that villager's unique house?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

The original 5 villagers on your island all get very generic houses. For instance, on my island, Maddie's house is very generic looking with a normal wooden floor and walls and whatnot because she moved in with my second wave with furniture I crafted.

However, Maddie's house interior is normally supposed to look like this:

[image: Maddie's unique house interior, a sort of picnic setup]

This looks way better than the generic house she's in now. Is there any way to force the game to update all of my early villagers' houses to become their unique designs?

Answer (score 4):

I've heard one solution is to get that villager to leave, then invite them back using the Amiibo feature.
This isn't so much an update as it is just a fresh villager that happens to be the same, but so far that's the only way I've seen.

I've seen nothing in Isabelle's or the villager's dialogue to prompt them to change their design.

Comment: I've also seen people pair up so that one of them encourages the villager to move out, the other picks them up, then does the same, so that they move back into the original town. This obviously requires some time travel to do efficiently.